# Mapr-Db bulkloading is failing at reducer end

Tags: hbase, bulk-load, hfile

Bulkload failed while processing the reducer with following error. We are running the mapreduce on M5 cluster trying to update a m7 table.

```
java.io.IOException: bulkLoaderClose() on '/home/test/account122' failed
with error: Function not implemented (38). 
at com.mapr.fs.Inode.checkError(Inode.java:1611) 
at com.mapr.fs.Inode.checkError(Inode.java:1583) 
at com.mapr.fs.Inode.bulkLoaderClose(Inode.java:1278) 
at com.mapr.fs.MapRHTable.bulkLoaderClose(MapRHTable.java:119) 
at com.mapr.fs.hbase.BulkLoadRecordWriter.close(BulkLoadRecordWriter.java:160)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:621)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:458)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:278)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1566) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:267)
```

hbase version is 0.98.12-mapr-1506.

The Mapr-Db table is enabled for bulkloading.
Reducers process all the data and at the time of bulkload it fails some how.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the MaprdDb tables do not support BulkLoading. The error Function not implemented (38) indicates that this feature is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

What is the utility you are using to Bulk load? You can use ImportTsv to bulk load into MapR-DB tables.

Comment: I was using MapReduce to do the bulk load using HFileOutputFormat2. The job runs but fails while moving the Hfiles. Did try ImportTsv. It also fails with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I tested below data file and import. Try if this works on your cluster.

1) Add below data to a mfs in your cluster. Replace it with your path ./mapr/demo.mapr.com/home/datafile.csv:
2014,1,1,1,3,2014-01-01,AA,N338AA,1,JFK,LAX,0914,14.00,1238,13.00,0.00,,385.00,359.00,2475.00,,,,,,
2014,1,1,2,4,2014-01-02,AA,N338AA,1,JFK,LAX,0857,-3.00,1226,1.00,0.00,,385.00,340.00,2475.00,,,,,,

export CF="cf1"

2) maprcli table delete -path /home/test/account122
3) maprcli table create -path /home/test/account122
3) maprcli table cf create -path /home/test/account122 -cfname $CF

## run import job

4)java -cp `hbase classpath` org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv \
    -Dimporttsv.separator=, \
    -Dimporttsv.columns=$CF:year,$CF:qtr,$CF:month,$CF:dom,$CF:dow,HBASE_ROW_KEY,$CF:carrier,$CF:tailnum,$CF:flightnumber,$CF:origin,$CF:dest,$CF:deptime,$CF:depdelay,$CF:arrtime,$CF:arrdelay,$CF:cncl,$CF:cnclcode,$CF:elaptime,$CF:airtime,$CF:distance,$CF:carrierdelay,$CF:weatherdelay,$CF:nasdelay,$CF:securitydelay,$CF:aircraftdelay,$CF:dummy \
    /home/test/account122 \
    /mapr/demo.mapr.com/home/datafile.csv

Comment: I realized after I sent you wanted to do bulk load. Please use below for bulk load:[mapr@maprdemo ~]$ cat voter_data 
1,david    Davidson,49,socialist,369.78,5108
2,priscilla steinbeck,61,democrat,111.76,2987

% hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.
columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,cf1:name,cf2:age,cf2:party,cf3:contribution_amount,cf3:
voter_number -Dimporttsv.separator=, -Dimporttsv.bulk.output=/user/mapr/dummy 
/user/mapr/voter_data_table  /user/mapr/voter_data

No HFiles are created in the output directory
[mapr@maprdemo ~]$ ls /user/mapr/dummy
_SUCCESS

[mapr@maprdemo ~]$

Comment: Before running importtsv create the table. hbase> create '/user/mapr/voter_data_table', {NAME=>'cf1'},